# ejs template variable is not defined on page load and errors

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have a form submitting to an express app:

```
app.post('/myform', function (req, res) {
    var content = new registration(req.body);
    content.save(function(errObj){
    if(errObj){
        res.render('registration',{error: errObj});
    } else {
        res.render('thankyou');
    }
});
```

If there are any errors in saving the form data to mongoDb I want to display those errors at the top of the form so I'm passing the error object back to the ejs template:

```
<% if (error) { %>
   <li><%= error %></li>  
<% } %>
```

But when I initially load the page and there are no errors yet (because the form has not been submitted) I'm receiving an error on the page and the form is not rendered:

```
error is not defined
```

How can I get around this?

Comment: Why did you edit your question? You removed the relevant part

Comment: when you open the page with get method at first time, the error is also undefined

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use a value in the error property that won't get through into the if:

```
res.render('registration', {error: false});
```

Comment: Of course! Thanks. Should have thought of that but still getting used to express/ejs

Comment: using ejs doesn't seem to work like using hbs in NestJS. Using hbs you can just return the variables as object, using EJS you can't.

Answer (score 30):

#### You can do that check in three ways :-

- Using the method suggested by Amit :

> **`res.render('registration', {error: false});`**

- Check to see if `error` exists like this :

> **`<% if( typeof(error) =="undefined")%>`** //checks the type of variable

- You can see if the variable `error` exists by accessing the `locals` object like this :

> **`<% if(locals.error) %>`**

Comment: this should be the right answer. getting your variable from the locals object is preventing ejs from throwing the undefined error.

Answer (score 5):

The following code explains a working example:

```
<% if (typeof error ='object' && error) { %>
    <li><%= error %></li>  
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Server: fast precessing

```js
<% if (typeof data != undefined) { %>
   <li><%= data %></li>  
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same problem and you can try it in two different ways.

1. Pass **false** to error on get from js file like below.

```js
router.get('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    res.render('login', { title: 'Please login',  error: false });
});
```

2. Another way is to handle it in ejs file, here you can check that error is passing from method call or not, like below.

```js
<% if (typeof error != "undefined" && error.username) {  %>
    <p><%= error.username.msg %></p>
<%} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try starting the server again by running the command
$ node server.js

Note: server.js is a user-defined file.

Comment: I had to do this. My variables wasn't defined yet.

Answer (score 0):

I know this was a couple of years ago at this point, but in case anyone else is stuck.

I resolved this issue by changing the scope of my variable(s) to global. Such an easy fix, but took me hours to figure out.

Instead of having the variable(s) in my `app.post` method, I moved everything to app.get. I then added `res.redirect()` to my `app.post` method and declared all my variable(s) at the top of my `js file`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting some varibles later after performing an action then  maybe you might consider setting them to null first. Lets say for example you want to render a page where you check cash balances after withdrawing some amount then on loading the page cash.ejs you'll get these undefined errors but you can fix this by initializing those variables to null first in the render function like this:

```
app.get("/cash", function (req,res){
    res.render ( "cash.ejs",{amount:"", charge:"", newbalance: ""});
});
```